# K-means in pyspark runing infinitely in jupyter notebook, works fine in zepplin notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-zeppelin

I am running a k-means algorithm in pyspark:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeansModel
import numpy as np
kmeans_modeling = KMeans(k = 3, seed = 0)
model = kmeans_modeling.fit(data.select("parameters"))
```

The data is a pyspark sql dataframe: `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`

However, the algorithm is running infinitely (it is taking much, much longer than supposed for the amount of data in the dataframe).

Does anyone know what could be causing the algorithm to behave like this? I ran this exact code for a different dataframe of the same type, and everything worked fine.

The dataset I used before (that worked) had 72020 rows and 35 columns, and the present dataset has 60297 rows and 31 columns, so it is not a size-related problem. The data was normalized in both cases, but I assume the problem has to be in the data treatment. Can anyone help me with this? If any other information is needed let me know in the comments and I will answer or edit the question.

EDIT:

This is what I can show about creating the data:

```
aux1 = temp.filter("valflag = 0")
sample = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("gs://LOCATION.csv").select("id")

data_pre = aux1.join(sample, sample["sample"] == aux1["id"], "leftanti").drop("sample")

data_pre.createOrReplaceTempView("data_pre")
data_pre = spark.table("data_pre")
data_pre = data.withColumn(col, functions.col(col).cast("double"))
data_pre = data_pre.na.fill(0)
data = vectorization_function(df = data_pre, inputCols = inputCols, outputCol = "parameters")
```

EDIT 2: I cannot provide additional information about the data, but I have now realized that the algorithm runs without problem in a zepplin notebook, but it is not working in a jupyter notebook; I have edited the tags and titel accordingly. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: could you show how `data` is created?

Comment: @mck edited the question!

Comment: your code snippet is full of undefined variables - please provide a minimal, reproducible example code.

Comment: @mck I have realized the problem probably doesn't lie with the data format or characteristics. I edited the question, title and tags accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation about running clustering jobs in Spark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html

Here is another, very similar, idea.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html